# Mandar parâmetros para uma interface C#

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Criei uma classe chamada `descricaoo` que vai receber por parâmetros alguns dados e vai adicionar em uma `List` de uma interface chamada `IInstrucao`. Mas da um erro "a classe descricaoo nao esta implementada a uma interface"
Como corrigir esse erro? Há outra maneira de mandar esses dados direto na interface `IInstrucao`?

```
class descricaoo:IInstrucao
{
   private string descricaobol;
   public descricaoo (int ibanco, int codigo, string descricaobol, int qtde)
   {
     this.descricaobol = descricaobol;
     List<IInstrucao> desci = new List<IInstrucao>();
     desci.Add(new descricaoo(ibanco,codigo,descricaobol,qtde));
   }  
 }

public interface IInstrucao
{
    IBanco Banco { get; set; }
    int Codigo { get; set; }
    string Descricao { get; set; }
    int QuantidadeDias { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ué, sua classe Descricao não está implementando as propriedades da Interface IInstrucao

Comment: Então, sua classe não tem os métodos nem as propriedades da interface...

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Está dizendo para implementar a interface, então faça isto:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {}
}

class descricaoo : IInstrucao {
    private string descricaobol;
    public descricaoo (int ibanco, int codigo, string descricaobol, int qtde) {
        this.descricaobol = descricaobol;
        List<IInstrucao> desci = new List<IInstrucao> { new descricaoo(ibanco,codigo,descricaobol,qtde) };
    }
    public IBanco Banco { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int QuantidadeDias { get; set; }
}

public interface IInstrucao {
    IBanco Banco { get; set; }
    int Codigo { get; set; }
    string Descricao { get; set; }
    int QuantidadeDias { get; set; }
}

public interface IBanco {}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QvygJH). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N4r2n0). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Interface.cs).

Comment: Obrigada bigown!

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa definir todos os itens da interface na classe, conforme [enuncia a arquitetura por contratos do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173156.aspx):

```
class descricaoo: IInstrucao
{
   private string descricaobol;
   public descricaoo (int ibanco, int codigo, string descricaobol, int qtde)
   {
     this.descricaobol = descricaobol;
     List<IInstrucao> desci = new List<IInstrucao>();
     desci.Add(new descricaoo(ibanco,codigo,descricaobol,qtde));
   }  

    public IBanco Banco { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int QuantidadeDias { get; set; }
 }

public interface IInstrucao
{
    IBanco Banco { get; set; }
    int Codigo { get; set; }
    string Descricao { get; set; }
    int QuantidadeDias { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ...tinha acabado de gerar a classe, ia postar quando vi o alerta de nova resposta. *Mal posso ver seus movimentos!*

Comment: Obrigada Cigano!